# Should I care if some system forms a group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, dynamical-systems

I am currently studying a discrete dynamical system where the function composition on the set of periodic points forms a finite group.

From a dynamical systems perspective, is there any reason to care about this property?  Would it be worth continuing to study the properties of this group?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have checked that each element does have an inverse, note that:

> The set if iterates on the set of periodic points is finite if and only if there is a maximal period.

So it is fair to say that nothing else can be learned.